# How can I insert a chart in this Google Apss Script?

Tags: xcode, google-apps-script, charts

I have the following code below and want to insert a chart in the new sheet, that uses the values of the IMPORTRANGEURL!  The code works fine apart from that problem. Do you have any ideas?

```
function freezeImportRange() {
  var importRangeUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11lx7OPRXTV9xwqhCVcFPcpL43glyy_9y-PPIC1ADzhk/edit#gid=0";
  var importRangeA1 = "Sheet1!A1!:AX80";


  var importedValues = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(importRangeUrl).getRange(importRangeA1).getDisplayValues();

  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("New Sheet");
  var ss = newSheet.getSheetByName(newSheet.getSheets()[0].getName());

  ss.getRange(1, 1, importedValues.length, importedValues[0].length).setValues(importedValues);

}
```

It should contain the following values, but I have no idea how to insert it in my code?

```
 chart = chart.modify()
  .asComboChart()
  .addRange(newSpreadsheet.getRange('B48:AX77'))
  .addRange(newSpreadsheet.getRange('B78:AX78'))
  .addRange(newSpreadsheet.getRange('B40:AX40'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'absolute')
  .setOption('series.1.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.2.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.3.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.4.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.5.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.6.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.7.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.8.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.9.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.10.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.11.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.12.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.13.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.14.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.15.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.16.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.17.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.18.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.19.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.20.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.21.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.22.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.23.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.24.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.25.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.26.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.27.type', 'LineChart')
  .setOption('series.28.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('height', 505)
  .setOption('width', 817)
  .setPosition(1, 3, 116, 4)
  .build(); 
  newSheet.insertChart(chart);
};
```

I think I have to set    var chart = ????????.getCharts()[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class Sheet has a [`getCharts()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCharts()) method that returns an array of every chart in the sheet. In order to obtain your chart you could use the following code:

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
```

After getting the chart object, you may call any method to it of the ones declared in the [`EmbeddedChart`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart.html) class.

Comment: It does not insert a chart in the new sheet: Error: TypeError: newSheet.insertChart is not a function (Zeile 114, Datei "Code")

Comment: Hey @greenster10, in the code you originally published, the variable `newSheet` is, in fact, an instance of [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet). This class does not have the `insertChart()` method. In order to properly insert it, you will have to call this method on an instance of [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) (in your original code, that would be the variable `ss`). Let me know if that works for you. Cheers

Comment: can you help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59028017/how-can-i-open-a-spreadsheet-in-a-new-tab-with-a-button