# How can i open a spreadsheet in a new tab with a button?

Tags: button, google-apps-script

I want to create a button in a googlesheet/google Apps Script that opens an existing google sheet in a new tab when u click on it. I will insert the button in a google sheet, so i basically just need a code that i link to the button.
The code below does not work somehow?
Can you help me?

```
function openURL(){
  var button = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText("This button opens a link in an overlay window")
    .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
        .setUrl("google sheet")
        .setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.OVERLAY)
        .setOnClose(CardService.OnClose.RELOAD_ADD_ON));
};
```

Comment: Hey again, greenster10. Where are you willing to place your button? From your code, I assume that the button will be located in an add-on - is that correct?

Comment: the button will be in a sheet, the code is completely useless i think?

Comment: the code is not completely useless - it could be used with addons. However, that is clearly not what you want, so it is indeed useless for the given context ;). I have published an answer, kindly let me know if it works for you or whether you have any issue with it. Cheers

Comment: i try it, thx man!

Comment: No worries! Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in case my answer was useful to you. Otherwise, don't hesitate to ask back any doubt you may have. Have a good one!

Comment: @carlesgg97 could you please help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135936/why-does-a-deleted-name-create-the-following-error-from-a-linked-list?noredirect=1#comment104499785_59135936

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to create such button and functionality, you will have to:

1. Create the code that will be executed upon clicking it. Go to Tools>Script Editor. Paste the following code (replacing, of course, the url for the appropriate one):

   ```js
   function openMySpreadsheet() {

     var url = 'YOUR_SHEET_URL';

     var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('js');
     htmlTemplate.url = url;
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlTemplate.evaluate().setHeight(10).setWidth(100), 'Opening Sheet...');
   }
   ```
2. Still from the Google Apps Script IDE, go to File>New>HTML File. Set the file name to be `js` and paste the following code into it:

   ```js
   <script>
     window.open('<?=url?>', '_blank', 'width=800, height=600');
     google.script.host.close();
   </script>
   ```
3. Go back to your Sheets document and insert an image using Insert>Image>Image **over** cells and select any image you would like to have as your button.
4. Select the newly created image and click on the 3 dots that appear on the top-right corner of it. Click on "Assign script", and put the function name to be run (in this case, `openMySpreadsheet` would work).

From now on, each time you click on the button, a short-lived dialog will be shown up (that is necessary in order to open a link on a new tab) and the link will be automatically open.

Comment: could you please help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135936/why-does-a-deleted-name-create-the-following-error-from-a-linked-list?noredirect=1#comment104499785_59135936