# Why does a deleted name create the following error from a linked list?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list called Assignment in which names appear (dropdown list). [image: Assignment] These names are assigned certain values, they are in the same line. The names are defined in a worksheet called Input Data! [image: Input Data]
If I now delete a name like Green, John from the Input Data worksheet, then I get the following error in another worksheet (Evaluation). In this evaluation worksheet the values are evaluated by the following formula: [image: Evaluation]    [image: Project Overview]

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF((IF($B$2="dontcare",1,REGEXMATCH(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577,$B$2 &"*")))*(IF($B$3="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$E$3:$E$577=$B$3)))*(IF($B$4="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$D$3:$D$577=$B$4)))*(IF($B$5="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$F$3:$F$577=$B$5)))*(IF($B$6="dontcare",1,(Assignment!$B$3:$B$577=$B$6))),(Assignment!S$3:S$577)))), 1, 1)
```

The following error appears in the evaluation sheet:
Error:
During the evaluation of VLOOKUP the value "Green, John" was not found.
[image: ERROR]

So my only question is, how to write a script that deletes the complete lines in the assignment list, if a line occurs with a name like Green, John, that is not in the input data list. short version: Example! Assignment sheet: line 7 Green, John -> check if Green, John is in sheet Input Data in row C! If Green, John is not in Input Data row C -> delete line 7 Green, John in Assignment!     .... That is basically my question!
example sheet with explanation: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OU_95Lhf6p0ju2TLlz8xmTegHpzTYu4DW0_X57mObBc/edit#gid=1763280488

Comment: sensitive data, not possible, sorry

Comment: @player0 I edited the question, can you help me now?

Comment: I wish but I would need to see it. can you setup a spreadsheet with fake data and recreate the issue and share that sheet?

Comment: That is a bit complicated, I try, but do you understand what I mean? The Iferror function could be an option, but the values can change, so they are variable

Comment: Probably a macro that solves this would be more fitting!

Comment: @player0 I did insert more information to the Question, I forgot to mention, that when you delete a name in the Input data sheet, this error occurs in the Evaluation sheet

Comment: @greenster10 you need to create a sample sheet reproducing this problem, then share it with us so we can see what you are talking about. If the sheet is too complicated to reproduce the problem then you don't have a single problem or question relevant to this site. You don't need a script to solve this problem but without a very specific isolated example of your issue there is no specific answer to give you.

Comment: What is summe and wenn? You need to provide a sample sheet or this question is definitely too vague because your issue can be anywhere, in fact here is a solution: delete everything and just try to solve the exact problem you have.

Comment: Sum and IF is Summe and Wenn

Comment: @player0 I edited the question and took pictures from an example sheet, do you need any more information?

Comment: @CodeCamper I edited the question and took pictures from an example sheet, do you need any more information?

Comment: This is question #59135936. Is your other question (#59140197) a duplicate of this question?

Comment: @greenster10 The comments that I made on question#59140197 apply here also 1) Images of screenshots are no substitute for the actual spreadsheet. It's no accident that 4 days passed without further comment - users are waiting for you to share a copy of your spreadsheet. It is really in your best interests. 2) the images that you have inserted in your question are forcing text to wrap such that the question is now unintelligible. I suggest that you review your question, and the positioning of the text and images.

Comment: example sheet with explanation: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OU_95Lhf6p0ju2TLlz8xmTegHpzTYu4DW0_X57mObBc/edit#gid=1763280488

Comment: So my only question is, how to write a script that deletes the complete lines in the assignment list, if a line occurs with a name like Green, John, that is not in the input data list. short version: Example! Assignment sheet: line 7 Green, John -> check if Green, John is in sheet Input Data in row C! If Green, John is not in Input Data row C -> delete line 7 Green, John in Assignment!     .... That is basically my question!